# Is there a way in for...of loops to capitalize the first letter in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Write a for...of loop that
*loops through each day in the days array
capitalizes the first letter of the day
and prints the day out to the console*

And Here is the code which I have written. But doesn't get the desired output. Could you please help me to resolve the problem.

```
 const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];


  for(let day of days){
 console.log(day.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
  }
```

Comment: Try mutating the `days` array while iterating. (need to use a standard `for` loop to assign, not `for..of`. or, push to another array)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I expect their homework is strict and they do just want the output, rather than modify the array.

Comment: Hi! You've successfully looped through the days and capitalized the first letter, so you're already three-quarters of the way there. Good work! Keep going! Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and try to finish the work. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You capitalize the first letter of the string:

```
day.charAt(0).toUpperCase()
```

So for `sunday` that will be `S`. Now you only have to concat (`+`) the rest of the string, in this case `unday`. To get that you can use `String.substr`:

```
day.substr(1)
```